# Sametime Rest API buddylist

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, sametime

I'm using sametime rest api.
I'm connecting to my server by URL = "http://servername:port/stwebapi/user/connect?"
I have a return code 200 OK. So I'm right connected.

When I try to recovering mu buddylist with URL = "http://servername:port/stwebapi/buddylist"
I alway receive an error 11 : which is "Please login to Sametime".

Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the LtpaToken or LtpaToken2 cookies you got after login with your request.